# Java user specified input file on one line

Tags: java

Most of what I see online is how to read a predefined file.

```
 File file = new File("myfile.txt");
```

There's another thread on how we can read user input after asking the user for it.  (ie `Please enter input:`)

I want to do something like `java main < inputfile`  How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: you mean you want to give filename from user while running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to do something like `java main < inputfile` How can I do this?

Change that to `java main inputfile.name`, then in the `main(String[] args)` it will be the 0th argument.  E.G.

```
File file = new File(args[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run launch application as `java MainClass < inputfile`, the file will be available as input-steam (`System.in`) to the application.

So you can do something as follows to read the contents of the file:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

//or

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```